# Customize dynamically created elements adding an option choosed via popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a little code that creates elements (rectangles) and when I pass the mouse over them, a "customize yellow button appears on it". When I click this button, a popup with colors let us choose a colour to add in the selected rectangle.

Basically, I have 3 elements... click on 1 of them and choose a colour. This action, clones de  tag and set it into the selected item. This works fine.

The problem appears when I click in the second item (or third)... I choose a new different colour but the action changes the selected rectangle and the sibling -applies to all elements that already have a cloned - (like propagation)...

I need to customize every single rectangle with its own colour and not all of them with the same. I pasted a little code here and a working (wrong) link in jsfiddle.

The action executes "on" cause the items are created dynamically (in this example I set them manually.

Can anybody help me? I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/martiniglesias/20Laxn84/2/

```
$(document).on("click","a.person",function (e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    var elrel=$(this).attr('rel');
    var elem=$("#ch_dndBoard1 span[data-id="+elrel+"]");
    var elemrel=elem.attr("rel");

    if (elemrel=="f1E")
    {
        $("body").append ("<div class='overlay'></div>").show();
        $(".persE").fadeIn("fast");

        $(".persE li").click(function(f)
        {
            f.preventDefault();
            f.stopPropagation();
            var ese=$(this).closest("li");
            if ($(this).hasClass("nope"))
            {
                elem.find('b').fadeOut("slow",function() { elem.find('b').remove(); });
            }
            else
            {
                elem.find('b').remove();
                var added=ese.find("b").clone();
                added.css({"left":0+"px","top":+5.48+"px","position":"absolute"});
                $(added).insertAfter(elem.find('em'));
            }
            $('.persE').fadeOut("fast",function(){ $(".overlay").remove(); });
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

I expect that every single rectangle can choose its own colour cloning it from the popup. For example, I want, rect1 blue, rect2 without color, rect3 red...

Thank you!

PS: Please, forgive my poor english :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this issue because you are adding a `click` event listener to `.persE li` **each time** you click on a `a.person`.

You need to remove that listener when all your logic is over:

```
$(".persE li").click(function(f) {
    // Your code

    $(".persE li").off('click');
});
```

Be aware that if you listen an other `click` event with a different logic, that one will be destroyed too.

In order to avoid this, you need to reference your different logics in function:

```
const changeColorEvent = (e) => {
    // Your code

    $(this).off('click', changeColorEvent); // Here, "otherEvent" will still exist.
};

const otherEvent = (e) => {
    // Different logic here
}

$(".persE li").click(changeColorEvent);
$(".persE li").click(otherEvent);
```

Comment: No problem. I just edited my answer to add an important detail.